# How to write a command in vimrc

Tags: linux, vim

I use the following command in vim when I open a file

```
:command -nargs=1 Inshtml :normal i You entered <args>^V<ESC>
```

It works, but it seems when I open another file the command deosn't exists... So, I want to write it in `vimrc` but I don't know how to define it there

Comment: Have you tried to put `command -nargs=1 Inshtml :normal i You entered <args>^V<ESC>` in $HOME/.vimrc ?

Comment: @Philippe yeah, it now works